# Creating a bumpy model without any maps

Tags: bump

I'm trying to create a model for 3D printing which needs many small bumps on it, meaning it needs to be in the physical model and not just as a bumpmap. Any tips on how I could create consistent bumps to my model?

Comment: you can use a Displace modifier then apply it, or even create random bumps with Mesh > Transform > Randomize, it depends a bit on the kind of object actually

Comment: Here is a [tutorial that shows how to use a displacement map at 7:11](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UkU0-QeWUcU&t=24s). A displacement map is like a bump map, but it actually changes the geometry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Geometry nodes solution (if you want regular bumps):

[image]

or a bit more randomized (scale + position)

[image]

This is an example of a sphere with some modifiers on it:

[image]

result:

[image]

Comment: Pefect! Thank you so much!

Comment: you are welcome!

Comment: @VDESC I haven't got a 3D printer, so I'm not sure about details... but to print it you of course have to apply the modifiers so that they become "real" geometry. And for the _Geometry Nodes_ solution, if you apply it the small spheres will also have faces inside the big sphere, I don't know if this is a problem for 3D printing.

Comment: @VDESC Just a quick thought: for the _Geometry Nodes_ solution, if you use a _Mesh_ > _Boolean_ node set to _Union_ instead of the _Join Geometry_, the small spheres will not continue inside the big sphere, this might be better for 3D printing.